# Thunderbird 3: create a single column to display the 'From' field on a received message and the 'Recipient' field on a sent message?

Tags: thunderbird

If the title doesn't say it all let me know. This would be helpful for IMAP folders within T-bird, when I'm looking through threads on a particular issue, but don't know if I sent the last message to the recipient, or they sent the last message to me.

I would be able to quickly scroll in one column and see exactly when the last communication on that issue was.

Is there a way to make a 'smart' column that would do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes - the [ShowInOut](http://www.ggbs.de/extensions/ShowInOut.html) extension does exactly that.

Comment: Fantastic! Exactly what I was looking for